# Is Logic App part of App services in Azure?

Tags: azure

I got confused on app services list. When I googled, some are saying Logic Apps part of App services, and some others say it is excluded from app services and currently app services include only webapps, api apps,function apps .

Could someone clarify, what is the correct updated app services list as of today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, azure logic app is not included in app service in Azure. This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/) is app service document, it shows the description of app service:
[image]

And this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview) is the document for logic app, it shows the description of logic app:
[image]

So logic app does not belong to app service.

Hope it would be helpful to your question~

Comment: I was wondering if you encountered the same issue as I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63960502/1232087).