# Azure - Associating network interfaces to an Application Security Group

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-security

**Question**: How do you associate a `Network Interface Card` of an Azure `Virtual Machine` to an [Application Security Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/application-security-groups)?

This [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-filter-network-traffic#associate-network-interfaces-to-an-asg) from MS Azure team describes how to add the `network interface` for a `VM` to one of the application security groups the tutorial has created previously. According to the tutorial, in the `Azure Portal`, you go to your `myVmWeb VM==>SETTINGS ==> Networking`. Then, Select `Configure the application security groups` as shown in image 1 below.

But when I follow these steps, I get the image 2 (shown below) that does not have the option `Configure the application security groups`. Moreover, all other tutorials that I searched online (such as [this](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/cloud_and_networking/9781789800227/3/ch03lvl1sec34/associating-an-asg-with-a-vm) and [this](https://petri.com/understanding-application-security-groups-in-the-azure-portal)) showing the same image 1 that MS Azure team's tutorial is showing. So, what I may be missing here or is there any other way to associate a VM's NIC to an Application Security Group?

**Azure Portal: Networking blade of a VM shown in the official MS Tutorial**:

[image]

**Azure Portal: Networking blade of the same VM when I follow the same MS Tutorial**:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry! my previous answer was wrong as I over looked on the NSG and ASG. Application Security Group Configuration moved to a tab as marked in the image-2 shared by you.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow`. You may have mistakenly thought of [ASG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/application-security-groups) as [NSG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-groups-overview). According to MS Azure tutorial, when you go to any `VM==>Settings==>Networking`, you will see on the left pane an option of `Application Security Groups` (as shown in image 1 above). But if you try this in Azure Portal now for any VM, you won't see that option (as image 2 is a prove of it).

Comment: Thanks for the welcome & you are right I misunderstood between NSG and ASG. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: Very good. Thank you for pointing out the new change in the Azure Portal. Your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 0):

To provide an updated answer: The ability to associate an Azure Virtual Machine Network Interface Card with an Application Security Group can now be completed via the main left pain on the Virtual Machine view.

[image]

[image]